# Limit rotation angle of camera in X axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

My camera is always looking at an object `A`. I added a piece of code so that the camera can rotate around `A` in the X axis, as shown below:

[image]

My code is this and runs every frame, moving the camera according to mouse vertical movement:

```cs
offset = transform.position - A.position;
offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), transform.right) * offset;
transform.position = A.position + offset;
transform.LookAt(A.position);
```

It works fine but when the camera tries to get to an angle of more than 90 in X axis, it starts to bug and reverse the image. How can I limit the camera angle so that it moves only from 0 degrees to 90 degrees? When the game starts, the camera is looking at `A` from an angle of 30º in X axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
     var rot = yourCamera.transform.rotation;
     rot.x = Mathf.Clamp(rot.x ,0,90);
     yourCamera.transform.rotation = rot;
}
```

that `Mathf.Clamp` will do the job and keep `X` value within boundaries.

Comment: The angle is not alone is attached to the movement of the camera, I guess only clamping the angle isn't the solution since it may desynchronize the angle of vision and the position.

Answer (score 0):

If your green Vector is A local Y, and blue is A local Z (as Unity):
You can fix your solution:

```
// Fix.
offset = transform.position - A.position;
offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), transform.right) * offset;
transform.position = A.position + offset;

Vector3 AUp = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90f, -A.right) * offset;
transform.LookAt(A.position, AUp);
```

And clamping like this:

```
// Clamp.        
offset = transform.position - A.position;
offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), transform.right) * offset;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(A.InverseTransformPoint(offset).z, A.InverseTransformPoint(offset).y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

if (angle > 90f && angle < 180f)
{
    transform.position = A.position + offset;
    Vector3 AUp = Quaternion.AngleAxis(90f, -A.right) * offset;
    transform.LookAt(A.position, AUp);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. In fact, with this codes, the camera doesn't move anymore.

Comment: Can you upload some screenshots from Unity to see your axis?